# Does Groff have an updated formatting algorithm (Knuth-Plass/other)?

Tags: groff, roff

In the [groff mission statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/groff/groff-mission-statement.html#core) it says that Groff will be moving to an improved formatting algorithm. Considering that the mission statement was written in 2014; I was wondering where this was at development wise. There is nothing I've seen in the git logs that might indicate this has been worked on/completed, but there is a [mailing list archive that shows some development.](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/groff/2017-11/msg00079.html)

Thank you very much in advance for any help

Answer (score 2):

It is very slow because there is very few people involved and none of us is getting any younger. I'm probably one of the youngest official contributors to the project and I have not participated actively in maybe 12 years.

Rather than ask, it would be great if you do the legal paperwork with the FSF to become a contributor and roll up your sleeves. We'll all thank you deeply. That goes for anyone reading this answer.